# How to do this custom report in Microsoft CRM 2013?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, reporting, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2013

I need to do some custom reports, and I'm kind of lost.

I want to do a custom report with the following conditions: number of emails and phone calls per day/week/months and per country

How can I do that ? do I need to use or create views to successfully make this kind of report ? I'm a new user of Dynamics CRM 2013. I spent a lot of time on it and I havn't found the solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

Creating new views won't really help. I'd tackle this with an SSRS Report.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328097.aspx

There are a lot of blogs and videos out there that step through creating an SSRS report. Here's a video that may be helpful:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wTpoW_cz0Xk